# Piano vibration recording

Tags: recording, production

How to record a grand piano vibration, but not a sound?

Ok, we all know, the vibration is a part of the sound, but anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to use a vibration meter that records vibration spikes on a graph. This would be similar to the machines that detect earth quakes, volcano eruptions. If you mean record the vibrations in some type of sound format, this is impossible sound IS vibration, they are not two separate things if you did not want any sound then you cant have vibrations.